# ASP.Net 4.0 OnTextChanged event is not firing in ItemTemplate (ListView)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, .net-4.0, updatepanel

Why I cant access OnTextChanged event? I already add AutoPostBack="true" in the textbox. Already tried to debug but still not firing.

Below are the sample codes:

**.ASPX Code**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:ListView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**.VB Code**

```
Protected Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim TextBox1 As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
    Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

What I'm missing here ?

---

**Solved**

I binding the datasource in Page Load. After changing to OnPreRender, its working!

Comment: that code should work. did you try to put a break point in your TextBox1_TextChanged and debug to see if it stops there?

Comment: yup put a break point but debugger not hitting there

Comment: does your debugger stop at other break points? are there javascript errors after page is loaded?

Comment: @RayCheng put break point at page load, after autopostback the textbox, still debugger not hitting TextBox1_TextChanged. No javascript error detected

Comment: that is weird but your code and concept is fine so i suggest you create a new simple project and add your other code little by little to see which one breaks it.

Comment: Why not bind it via `ItemDataBind` on the `ListView` control? Then during `Page_Load`, you just need to `ListView1.DataSource = data;` and then `ListView1.DataBind();`?

Comment: @RayCheng as im using oracle for the backend, I need to query the data first using store procedure and return as datatable to the listview.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a ScriptManager on the page?  That would be one idea I'd have.

Comment: yup. ScriptManager has been include in the page. I dont have any problem with the ajax listview pagination

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's the textbox that is the problem?  Label1 would also have to be in the update panel to display the new value; only the update panel regions update when the async postback fires.  Make sure Label1 is in an UpdatePanel with it's UpdateMode="Always" set.

Check the javascript that a __doPostback is defined within the markup of the event handler of the textbox (should be onblur, but may be onchange).

Comment: it may not update the label, but debugger should stop tho. os that shouldn't be the problem.